# Is there a plugin for WordPress that will let me transform the string "LaTeX" into the proper format?

Tags: wordpress, latex

I write quite a bit about TeX and friends and inevitably refer to them by name in my posts.

Is there any way to replace every occurrence of `TeX`, `LaTeX`, or `foo` with custom HTML?

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8160514

Comment: From our [help/on-topic]: _"Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here: ... Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB"_

Comment: My apologies. I did read the help center since this is a new site to me (I'm usually on [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17423/sean-allred)), that line must have missed my eye.  I would recommend on Meta that the bullet's wording be revised, though.  To me, 'hosted scripts' is a meaningless term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Yes, there is a plugin called [Text Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/text-replace/) for WordPress.org. You just enter a shortcut and what you want to replace it with:

> {shortcut} => {replace with}

For your case, for instance:

```
LaTeX => <span class='latex'>L<sup>a</sup>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>
TeX => <span class='tex'>T<sub>e</sub>X</span>
```

By the way, I put `LaTeX` before `TeX` on purpose. If you read the plugin's page, you'll understand why.